# Mailchimp - HTML - Magento - Automation of Templates

Tags: html, magento, email, rss, mailchimp

i am currently working on coding HTML Templates for an E-Commerce Shop (Magento).
We want to send out daily Mails with recently uploaded products.
Right now, we would have to dive in to the html each time, change img tags etc. for each product (about 10 per mail).

So here is my question: Is it possible to automate put in new products automatically each day? I've read about the Magento RSS Feed and the Combination of Mailchimp Mergetags to display the latest products. Is this the best way to do this or are there any other ways to automate this?

I talked to some Friends of mine, who said that RSS is supposedly "dead" and this would be, if it would even work, rather a quick hack than a long-term sustainable solution.

So I would be thankful if someone has an insight here.

Comment: This question is very broad and unclear. You will have to provide some example code or specific problems that will help people to assist you.

Comment: RSS is anything but 'dead', they are probably the same people who dis email. Where do they think most content reading apps get their content from?? Just because it is wrapped in an app...

Answer (score 0):

This is a viable solution. Besides this, you'd probably have to look into the API's of each service. Ultimately the API would give you the most 'automatic' result, but it would take some coding to set that up for your specific needs.

Give the RSS a go.